# Error when reimplement my own QDialog::exec()

Tags: c++, overriding, qt5, c++14, qdialog

I'm using Qt 5.7

In my `.h` :

```
public slots:
    QList<int> exec();
```

In my `.cpp` :

```
QList<int> DIALOG_Generic::exec() {
    QList<int> symsId;

    BasicParameterDialog::exec();

    if (result() == QDialog::Accepted)
        foreach (const Parameter &p, parameters())
            symsId << p.symbolID;

    return symsId;
```

And bellow `error` occured :

> error: conflicting return type specified for 'virtual QList SymbolTable::DIALOG_Generic::exec()'

When i have compiled with Qt 4.8.7 this code doesn't have problem.
If i can't return a different type from `int` how can i get my list of parameters?

Comment: Make `QList<int>` a member of `DIALOG_Generic`.

Comment: then i can create a function to get my parameters after call exec??? @nwp